# Update basic jQuery script to use ScrollTo function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion, scrollto

I have a jQuery SlideDown/SlideUp Demo here: https://tinker.io/8e585/15

Is it possible that when I click the 'Test 2' link, **the viewport moves down to that part of the page**? So 'Test 2' would then appear at the top of the window?

I had tried: `$(window).scrollTop($('div#box2').offset().top)` but was having issues in FF.

Any ideas of a simple solution to this?

Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#box2 h2").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $this.offset().top
    }, 1000);

    return false;

});
```

Working demo: https://tinker.io/8e585/16

Comment: Wow! That works beautifully. Many thanks for taking the time to help and for giving such an accurate answer.